# How can I reset all network settings in Linux Mint?

Tags: networking, linux-mint

I'm using Mint 14 and i completely hosed the network settings. How can i reset them all back to default.

Comment: You will have to do this by hand because the installer does the Network Conf. See http://serverfault.com/questions/156517/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-reconfigure-etc-network-interfaces-for-me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't really clear as to what you've done, with what privileges (root?), or what the consequences/problems are.

Anyhow, try (re)moving: `~/.gconf/system/networking/`

And if it doesn't work, try: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

If it is `NetworkManager` related. If you played with `ifconfig` and other tools, take a look at:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

To be sure the changes take effect, the best option is to log out and log in again, or reboot if you changed anything in `/etc` . Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

try renaming the folder called ".gconf" in your home folder, (this will reset some OS user-made changes) then log out and back in.
dunno if it will solve it, but if it doesn't, you can rename it back and restore your settings.

aamof, the network settings are not focused on a single file, but distributed among several, working together.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, because i did it under root.

Answer (score 1):

you open up the terminal and type in these commands

```
service network-manager stop
rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
service network-manager start
```