# Suddenly unable to access the internet; works fine booting from USB drive

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint xfce 21.2 Victoria, which I just installed two days ago, and everything has been working fine, except today I was suddenly unable to browse the internet.

Using the hotspot on my phone I was able to `ping 8.8.8.8`, but couldn't reach any website. `nslookup` times out and gives me the following error message:

```
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
```

There is another wifi network where I am staying that is behind a login wall. Normally when I connect to it, I am rerouted to the login page, but not anymore.

I still have the USB stick I used to install. So I booted from that, and it worked fine. I was able to browse connected to both my hotspot and the other network mentioned above, which suggests this is a software issue.

How do I fix this? I really don't want to reinstall the entire system. Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: Try a different user profile

Comment: Did the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: The problem persists after reboot, and it does work from a different profile. I had ProtonVPN installed but purged it. It has caused small troubles before. So should I try resetting all the network settings? How do I do that?

Comment: Follow this post:     https://superuser.com/questions/517678/how-can-i-reset-all-network-settings-in-linux-mint

Comment: @John I actually found that before I wrote this post but it seems to be out of date. I don't have a .gconf folder in my home directory.

Comment: Try:  sudo apt-get --fix-missing update ....   to get missing updates.   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   ...   to install new dependencies   then     sudo apt-get update  sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: Sorry, @John, I was mistaken. It still isn't working even on a different user profile. The update manager seemed to be working but I pressed refresh and it timed out, and I'm unable to browse. So it's not at the user level.

Comment: It appears you may need to reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Mysteriously, as I was trying to figure out a way to get the work I've done off my sdd so I could reinstall without losing it, it started working again.

Comment: I would be inclined to run the repair steps I outlined to help ensure longer term stability